# mssql statements on Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I am a beginner programmer and I am having difficult to understand this statement.

```
.input('pCodigoPedidoSAP', mssql.VarChar(16), filter.codigoPedidoSap)
```

What means the dot before input, and what exactly input function does. The 'pCodigoPedidoSAP' is a parameter from my SQL procedure.

Thanks

Comment: The dot chains the method to the object which you are not showing in your post.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input-name-type-value

> Add an input parameter to the request.

it has to be chained to a request.

what you're doing is :

`REQUEST_INSTANCE.input('pCodigoPedidoSAP', mssql.VarChar(16), filter.codigoPedidoSap)`

which basically says:

add me a VarChar param named `pCodigoPedidoSAP` of 16 characters and assign it the value of `filter.codigoPedidoSap`